# React native unsupported url (IOS)

Tags: ios, react-native

Please help to solve Error: unsupported URL (IOS).When i adding data to url from reducer it not working but normally when adding url to fetch data without reducer data it error.(Same code works in Android )

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I solved with remove spaces i dont know where is space but when i get link from reducer and then replace space to empty and all solved

Answer (score 8):

There may be some value in your query string with special characters (like spaces). Try encoding the api url using [encodeURI()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURI) in javascript. Or, if you are passing another url in your api query params then you may have to encode symbols which are reserved for urls (for eg: ?, :, / etc.) use [encodeURIComponent()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURIComponent) for this case. This resolved the same issue for me.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. My URI was working on Android but not IOS with an expo library. I spent days on it, trying a dozen things with no luck. But encodeURI solved it.

Comment: OMG, I almost spent 2 days and went through almost 100+ sites. Finally just one line changed the code. Thanks alot man.